# autoresizing column header in visual basic datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, resize

I've been trying to resize the header column in my program as it cuts off an important row label. AutoSizeColumnsMode and AutoResizeColumns() doesn't work. All my attempts so far have lead to the other columns been resized, however not the header column.[Image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzTKs.png)

```
Dim dgv_flightTemplate As New DataGridView
    Dim c As Integer = txb_columns.Text
    Dim r As Integer = txb_rows.Text
    For colcount As Integer = 0 To c - 1
    Dim nc As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    nc.Name = "Seating Column"
    dgv_flightTemplate.Columns.Add(nc)
    Next
    dgv_flightTemplate.Rows.Add(r)
    dgv_flightTemplate.Rows(0).HeaderCell.Value = "A -"
    Me.Controls.Add(dgv_flightTemplate)
  dgv_flightTemplate.Location = New Point(400, 400)
    dgv_flightTemplate.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    dgv_flightTemplate.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    dgv_flightTemplate.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
    dgv_flightTemplate.AutoResizeColumns()
```

also note this has to be done programmatically because i am creating the datagridview from the size the user gives

Thanks for any replies,
Taine

Comment: So, you're actually saying that you want to resize the column of row headers, not a column header, right?

Comment: If so then you should be using the `RowHeadersWidthSizeMode` property, which I didn't even know existed previously but just found in a matter of seconds by reading the documentation for the `DataGridView` class.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks, this worked was expected. I'm quite new to visual basic and datagridviews